# Hashmap to query

Tags: java, rest, url

I am working on HTML5+JS api based website, but all I can get is APK Java Sources for API, because there is no any documentation.

I got API raw URLs from it looking like:
http://api-test.com/?key=value

But as I can trace with Wireshark APK never called raw URLs directly and using something like REST api url looking like this:
http://api-test.com/rest/?key=value

The problem is, that I can't understand what params are actually sents via REST api, because REST api urls somehow hashed all keys and values in something like this:

> http://api-test.com/rest/?s=cf9489a2823b900ec1119fa1847669ab9fab1c2b&d=V2rC84auKmgDAHuztpSmyMA4&t=1467399404811
>
> http://api-test.com/rest/?s=280f8a9454775de6a14d2b53da9088eb028bfe1a&d=V2rC84auKmgDAHuztpSmyMA4&t=1467399374801
>
> http://api-test.com/rest/?s=a395b00e56db6679c8aaf869d95aa1d1ccfb424c&d=V2rC84auKmgDAHuztpSmyMA4&t=1467399344791

Because I am not familar with Java at all, Is it possible to somehow convert this hashed data back to query?

This is some part from Java Source Code, I think relating to my APIs:

```
public PicSearchResult PicSearch(String isc, String q, String cid, int s, String rk, String shpc, String rg, String f, String cpid, String pid, int n, String isRtl, String isOn) throws AkServerStatusException, AkInvokeException, AeResultException {
    Param2Result<PicSearchResult> response = this.PicRawAPI.Pic_search("23b1k5ak91dll5d71s45h24l703la20d", isc, q, cid, s, rk, shpc, rg, f, cpid, pid, n, isRtl, isOn);
    WsmobileResultChecker.check(response);
    return (PicSearchResult) response.getBody(PicSearchResult.class);
}


public interface PicRawAPI {
    @AkAPI(url = "http://test-api.com/")
    @AkGET
    Param2Result<PicSearchResult> Pic_search(@AkParam("ak") String str, @AkParam("isc") String str2, @AkParam(encode = "UTF-8", value = "q") String str3, @AkParam("cid") String str4, @AkParam("s") int i, @AkParam("rk") String str5, @AkParam("shpc") String str6, @AkParam("rg") String str7, @AkParam("f") String str8, @AkParam("cpid") String str9, @AkParam("pid") String str10, @AkParam("n") int i2, @AkParam("isRtl") String str11, @AkParam("isOn") String str12) throws AkInvokeException, AkServerStatusException;
}


private HashMap<String, String> getRawApiParams2HashMap(Annotation[][] annosArr, Object[] args, HashMap<String, File> filesToSend, HashMap<String, String> paramsMapOri) {
    HashMap<String, String> paramsMap = new HashMap();
    for (int idx = 0; idx < args.length; idx++) {
        String paramName = null;
        String encode = NetWork.CONN_TYPE_NONE;
        for (Annotation a : annosArr[idx]) {
            if (AkParam.class.equals(a.annotationType())) {
                AkParam ap = (AkParam) a;
                paramName = ap.value();
                encode = ap.encode();
            }
        }
        if (paramName != null) {
            Map<String, String> arg = args[idx];
            if (arg != null) {
                if (encode != null && !NetWork.CONN_TYPE_NONE.equals(encode)) {
                    try {
                        paramsMap.put(paramName, URLEncoder.encode(arg.toString(), encode));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        Log.m6w(TAG, "UnsupportedEncodingException:" + encode);
                        paramsMap.put(paramName, arg.toString());
                    }
                    paramsMapOri.put(paramName, arg.toString());
                } else if ("$paramMap".equals(paramName)) {
                    Map<String, String> paramMap = arg;
                    paramsMap.putAll(paramMap);
                    paramsMapOri.putAll(paramMap);
                } else if (!"$filesToSend".equals(paramName)) {
                    paramsMap.put(paramName, arg.toString());
                    paramsMapOri.put(paramName, arg.toString());
                } else if (arg instanceof Map) {
                    filesToSend.putAll(arg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return paramsMap;
}

public static String encode(String str) {
        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(hexString.charAt((bytes[i] & 240) >> 4));
            sb.append(hexString.charAt((bytes[i] & 15) >> 0));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

public static String decode(String bytes) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length() / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length(); i += 2) {
        baos.write((hexString.indexOf(bytes.charAt(i)) << 4) | hexString.indexOf(bytes.charAt(i + 1)));
    }
    return new String(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

**UPDATE2**: Trying back conversion by myself, but catching errors :(

CODE:

```
public class HelloWorld {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String ap = "280f8a9454775de6a14d2b53da9088eb028bfe1a";
  byte[] bytes = ap.getBytes();
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length() / 2);
  for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length(); i += 2) {
   baos.write((hexString.indexOf(bytes.charAt(i)) << 4) | hexString.indexOf(bytes.charAt(i + 1)));
  }
  System.out.println(baos.toByteArray());
 }
}
```

ERROR:

```
   sh-4.3$ javac HelloWorld.java                                                                                                                                                                
HelloWorld.java:8: error: cannot find symbol                                                                                                                                                 
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length() / 2);                                                                                                          
        ^                                                                                                                                                                                    
  symbol:   class ByteArrayOutputStream                                                                                                                                                      
  location: class HelloWorld                                                                                                                                                                 
HelloWorld.java:8: error: cannot find symbol                                                                                                                                                 
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length() / 2);                                                                                                          
                                         ^                                                                                                                                                   
  symbol:   class ByteArrayOutputStream                                                                                                                                                      
  location: class HelloWorld                                                                                                                                                                 
HelloWorld.java:8: error: cannot find symbol                                                                                                                                                 
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length() / 2);                                                                                                          
                                                                    ^                                                                                                                        
  symbol:   method length()                                                                                                                                                                  
  location: variable bytes of type byte[]                                                                                                                                                    
HelloWorld.java:10: error: cannot find symbol                                                                                                                                                
                for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length(); i += 2) {                                                                                                                                
                                         ^                                                                                                                                                   
  symbol:   method length()                                                                                                                                                                  
  location: variable bytes of type byte[]                                                                                                                                                    
HelloWorld.java:11: error: cannot find symbol                                                                                                                                                
                        baos.write((hexString.indexOf(bytes.charAt(i)) << 4) | hexString.indexOf(bytes.charAt(i + 1)));                                                                      
                                                           ^                                                                                                                                 
  symbol:   method charAt(int)                                                                                                                                                               
  location: variable bytes of type byte[]                                                                                                                                                    
HelloWorld.java:11: error: cannot find symbol                                                                                                                                                
                        baos.write((hexString.indexOf(bytes.charAt(i)) << 4) | hexString.indexOf(bytes.charAt(i + 1)));                                                                      
                                    ^                                                                                                                                                        
  symbol:   variable hexString                                                                                                                                                               
  location: class HelloWorld                                                                                                                                                                 
HelloWorld.java:11: error: cannot find symbol                                                                                                                                                
                        baos.write((hexString.indexOf(bytes.charAt(i)) << 4) | hexString.indexOf(bytes.charAt(i + 1)));                                                                      
                                                                                                      ^                                                                                      
  symbol:   method charAt(int)                                                                                                                                                               
  location: variable bytes of type byte[]                                                                                                                                                    
HelloWorld.java:11: error: cannot find symbol                                                                                                                                                
                        baos.write((hexString.indexOf(bytes.charAt(i)) << 4) | hexString.indexOf(bytes.charAt(i + 1)));                                                                      
                                                                               ^                                                                                                             
  symbol:   variable hexString
```

Comment: A `HashMap` uses a hash (of the keys) to _internally_ store the key-value pairs and those hashes should not be visible/used outside the map. _Hashed_ values on the other hand are a form of encryption/encoding to either hide the actual parameter values or allow for more complex values (e.g. byte arrays, strings containing whitespace or special characters etc.). In your case I'd guess `ap.encode()` and `URLEncoder.encode(....)` results in those hashed values but I don't know what encoding is being used (`ap.encode()` seems to define the encoding).

Comment: I did search on `ap.encode` in all files realted to this APK, and there is only one place it meets I already provided above `encode = ap.encode();`

Maybe this line?
`public static String encode(String str) {
        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(hexString.charAt((bytes[i] & 240) >> 4));
            sb.append(hexString.charAt((bytes[i] & 15) >> 0));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }`